# Properties of division with remainder

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-domain

In the context of an abstract formalisation of division with remainder in an interactive theorem prover, I came upon the following problem: The following two properties seem rather natural for a division with remainder (for $b\neq 0$ and $c\neq 0$):

$$(a + c \cdot b)\ \mathrm{div}\ b = c + a\ \mathrm{div}\ b$$
$$(c \cdot a)\ \mathrm{div}\ (c \cdot b) = a\ \mathrm{div}\ b$$

Let's assume that we have a Euclidean domain. I was unable to prove that these properties hold for any division operation that fulfils the requirements of a Euclidean domain. (and I suspect that this is simply not true, although I haven't found a counterexample either)

My question is: What additional properties – ideally few, simple, and natural ones – do I have to assume to prove these two facts? Is there perhaps a standard algebraic structure where these hold?

I know of [uniquely Euclidean norms](http://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Filtrative_and_multiplicatively_monotone_implies_uniquely_Euclidean) and I think the properties should be relatively easy to infer in those. However, a number of interesting rings fulfil the two conditions I gave above, but they are not uniquely Euclidean: integers and, (if memory serves me right) formal power series over a field.

Comment: So is "$x \text{ div } y$" short for the division part, with the remainder deleted?

Comment: I'm not sure what your definition of division is, actually. My definition of Euclidean domain is that for any nonzero $a, b$ we can write $a = bq + r$ where the size of $r$ is less than the size of $b$. But there is not necessarily a *unique* way to write it, even in a nice ring like $\mathbb{Z}$, so we can't just define $a \text{ div } b$ to equal $q$.

Comment: $x\ \textrm{div}\ y$ and $x\ \textrm{mod}\ y$ are division/remainder operations that satisfy the conditions of a Euclidean domain (i.e. $(x\ \textrm{div}\ y) \cdot y + (x\ \textrm{mod}\ y) = x$ and $s(x\ \textrm{mod}\ y) < s(y)$ or $x\ \textrm{mod}\ y = 0$. I am aware that there are several possible choices for these operations, but once you want to do computations, you typically require one fixed division and remainder operations.

Comment: I'm not even sure whether the fact that we have a Euclidean ring really helps us here. Essentially, the question is: what nice/natural/standard properties do I have to demand for the two laws I mentioned to hold?